# 'float' object has no attribute 'arctan'

Tags: numpy, pandas, dataframe, sqrt

1. i have data as below.

   ```
    data                                                            
    62600.0    
    63000.0    
    62900.0    
    60400.0    
    59800.0
   ```
2. code is

   ```
      def Simplify(G_x,data):
          data['dx'] = data*G_x 
          data['dy'] = data - data.shift(1)
          data = data.fillna(0)
          data['G_mag'] = np.sqrt((data['dx']+data['dy'])*(data['dx']+data['dy'])-2*data['dx']*data['dy']) 
          data['Theta'] = np.arctan(data['dy']/data['dx'])
          data = data.fillna(0) 
          data['Theta']=0
          data.loc[data['Theta']<0,'Theta'] = data['Theta']+2*np.pi
          data.loc[(data['Theta']<=np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>=0), 'Theta'] = np.arctan(0)
          data.loc[(data['Theta']<=3*np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>1*np.pi/8), 'Theta'] = np.arctan(1)
          data.loc[(data['Theta']<=np.pi) & (data['Theta']>3*np.pi/8), 'Theta'] = np.arctan(2)
          data.loc[(data['Theta']<=13*np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>np.pi), 'Theta'] = np.arctan(-2)
          data.loc[(data['Theta']<=15*np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']>13*np.pi/8), 'Theta'] = np.arctan(-1)
          data.loc[(data['Theta']>15*np.pi/8) & (data['Theta']<=2*np.pi), 'Theta'] = np.arctan(0)
          data['New_dy'] = data['dx']*np.tan(data['Theta'])
          data['N_AC']=data['New_dy'].cumsum()+data['Adj Close'][0]
          return data['N_AC']
   ```

3.Error message is

```
           'float' object has no attribute 'arctan'
           'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

4. When i run this code directly,not using function. it works well. 
   is there any good way to solve this problem. thanks!

Comment: What is the second argument `G_x`?

Comment: G_x is int. I applied 0.1

Comment: Is your original `data` a dataframe or a series?

Comment: Check to see if you overwrote np somewhere. print type(np) on fourth line of function

Comment: It is dataframe. I used like this. Data['a'] = Simplify(0.1,data['b'].  data['b'] is what i expressed above.

Comment: piRSquared. I dont understand clearly.  Could u explain more in detail??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have created a global variable called `np` somewhere, so that when you write `np.sqrt` or `np.arctan` it tries to find the corresponding methods of the object `np` instead of calling numpy functions.

Or as it works when you don't use it as a function, it must be because it doesn't understand in the function the `np` means the package `numpy`. If you are working on notebooks such as jupyter, just add `import numpy as np` in the notebook you're function is in. If you only load `numpy` in the notebook from which you call the function, it will not understand what `np` refers to.

Comment: I just load numpy outside function. I will try what u commented. Hopefully succeed!  Thanks a lot

Comment: def Simplify(G_x,data):
             import numpy as np
             data['dx'] = data*G_x , i add what u suggested, but still meet same error message.  "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sort'"

Comment: It's not in the function itself, but in the beggining of the notebook in which your function is. Nevertheless it should work, and the new error is strange given that you don't even use a sort method in your function. What is the most recent callback of the error?

Comment: Sort is typo.  Sqrt.